# CSS button positioning keep changing on resize/zoom

Tags: html, css

I have big problems with css buttons... My screen size is 1366x768 and their position is just fine until I zoom out in browser or show it to someone who have bigger screen.

Can anyone help me, please?

Site with problems: http://riotpointscodes.info/region.html

Comment: Your hole HTML markup is very bad:(

Comment: Your problem is the absolute positioning of your buttons. But you should think about your complete architecture. The page is build in a kind of strange way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bored at work today and your graphics were pretty cool so....

Here you are my friend:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Riot Points Codes</title>
        <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://agessy.com/favicon.png" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/background.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top #070b14;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #wrapper {
                width: 895px;
                height: 493px;
                position:relative;
                top:180px;
                margin:0 auto;
                background: url('region_files/paper.jpg') no-repeat top center;
            }

            .choice {
                background: url("region_files/map.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
                height: 212px;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -259px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 43px;
                width: 517px;
            }

            .logo {
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -205px;
                position: absolute;
                top: -135px;
            }
            #lol-custom-buttons {
                position:   absolute;
                bottom: 107px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 90px;
                text-align:center
            }
            .play-free-link {
                height: 90px;
                width: 251px;
                background-repeat: none;
                color: #ECC873;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .play-free-link.one {
                background-image: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/1n.png");
            }

            .play-free-link.one:hover {
                background-image: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/1h.png");
            }

            .play-free-link.two {
                background-image: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/3n.png");
            }

            .play-free-link.two:hover {
                background-image: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/3h.png");
            }
            .play-free-link.three {
                background-image: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/2n.png");
            }

            .play-free-link.three:hover {
                background-image: url("http://riotpointscodes.info/images/2h.png");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo"><img src="region_files/logo.png"></div>
            <div class="choice"></div>
            <div id="lol-custom-buttons">
                <a class="play-free-link one" href="http://riotpointscodes.info/"></a>
                <a class="play-free-link two " href="http://riotpointscodes.info/"></a>
                <a class="play-free-link three" href="http://riotpointscodes.info/"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: further optimizations would be to use image sprites.

Comment: Thanks to all ya people and especially to TimWickstrom ;) 

Cheers! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You are positioning your buttons absolutley to the document body:

Example left button:

```
position: absolute;
top: 475px;
width: 251px;
```

Place all buttons in a container positioned over your paper and set the position to relative or absolute and then play with the placement of the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

When you use absolute positioning, you need an anchor point. The anchor point is the first element up the HTML tree that has `position:relative` defined. If no element is found, the BODY tag becomes the anchor point.

Since you have a wrapper with stuff inside it, this should be come your anchor point in order to keep everything inside even if the browser resizes, not the BODY.